# 100% container height issue - HTML5 / CSS2/3

Tags: html, layout, css

Simple problem, though apparently not a simple solution.

Example here: http://myhideout.eu/new/

Basically the site consist of two columns, though with no wrappers or anything like it, as I'd really like to do with as little of the sort as possible, partly for the sake of simplicity, but also to make use of the HTML5 semantics, which in my mind don't really include divs, no matter how appropriately they are be named.

However, I'd like to have the sidebar fill up the full height of the adjacent column, which is not as easy as I first thought it would be. I know it's an old problem, but I was sure I had solved it before.

Anyhow, I tried to figure out how to do it without using wrappers or JavaScript. JavaScript is a no go, but that's another story. I was sure that there would be some sort of smart CSS3 feature or something similar, that would solve my problem, without the need for wrappers, but my search for this much need feature was a failure of epic proportions.

So I said to my self: "Damn it! Oh well, just have to use wrappers then."

I was sure it would work. I tried different configurations, but no matter what I did, I couldn't get it to work without setting an absolute height of the surrounding wrapper. Just imagine my disappointment, failing once again when I was sure I had done it before. So again I went searching for a solution to suit my needs. Though a lot more material turned up this time, it was still a failure. The few solutions I found was questionable to say the least.

So, now I'm here again, asking yet another one of those questions which undoubtedly have been asked a quadrillion times before. I am sorry about this, but I really don't know where else to go.

I do hope you can help.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

edit:

This works exactly as I want it too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 800px;
      }
      #wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 800px;        
      }
      body > header, body > footer {
        background-color: red;
        width: 800px;
      }
      #wrapper > article {
        margin-right: 200px;
        width: 600px;
        background-color: blue;
      }
      #wrapper > aside {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>This is a header</header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <article>
        This is the content<br /><br /><br /><br />left<br /><br /><br /><br />left
      </article>
      <aside>
        And this is the sidebar! I dynamically make myself bigger based on the content on the left!
      </aside>
    </div>
    <footer>This is a footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Only problem left is getting rid of that damn div tag ;)

edit:
the css table display properties have been pointed out to me, and it really seems to be what I'm looking for, as the smart solution, but with multiple elements in one row, and only one in the other, I can't figure out how it should be done.

Comment: Is IE6 compatibility a requirement?

Comment: Certainly not. Only the newest browsers that are freely available, IE9, Firefox 4, etc.

Comment: I regards to my last edit, I just realised that if you know the height of the header and footer, you should be able to drop the div wrapper and use body instead.

Comment: Using HTML5's new semantic elements doesn't (and shouldn't) preclude using DIVs at all. When you have an element with some semantic value, beside grouping, use one of HTML5's new elements: section, article, etc. When you only need to group elements, without adding other semantic value, use a DIV. Wrappers (and 'liners') are not evil!

Comment: I realise that, however I certainly prefer to do without them. Not sure why really. But since I can, there's really not much left to say ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If IE6 compatibility is not a requirement, then I usually will usually do the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        This is the content
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        And this is the sidebar! I dynamically make myself bigger based on the content on the left!
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.container { position:relative; }
.content {margin-right:<SIDEBAR WIDTH HERE>;}
.sidebar {position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:???; }
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/geC3w/

This works in all modern browsers and Internet Explorer 7 and above, it's also immensely simple, as long as IE6 compatibility isn't a requirement

Comment: Only requirements are they newest browsers really. Firefox 4, IE9 and such. I'm not sure exactly how your suggestion is supposed to work, but I'll be sure to check it out ASAP. Thanks

Comment: @Zacariaz - Basically, it creates the sidebar as an absolutely positioned element, and stretches it to the size of the parent div by forcing both the top and bottom values to be zero. If you need to play with it, check out the JSFiddle link in my answer, and tinker with the HTML and CSS to your hearts content.

Comment: Well, it certainly works and if I'm smart enough I may even be able to avoid divs. Can't say I like absolute positioning very much, but I suppose I can make an exception. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just one gotcha: the content must be higher than the sidebar - http://jsfiddle.net/geC3w/1/ - though that rarely matters.

Comment: the important part is position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0;

Comment: @Zacariaz - You can replace the divs with whatever you want. Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pDSrQ/2/. There I've only added a single div container, but you can replace that with the appropriate semantic element if you need. I can relate to how you feel about absolute positioning, but then we wouldn't need it if the height CSS property acted intuitively. Don't forget to mark as answer if it worked by clicking the green tick on the left :-).

Comment: Absolute positioning has a bad rep from the IE6 days, but it's actually a very sane way of positioning

Comment: @thirtydot - That is true, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I don't really think there are any semantic elements suitable purely for a wrapper. I will of course mark the answer, and will do so soon, but you never know if some better and absolutely ingenious solution pops up ;)

Comment: BTW, that jsfiddle thing is amazing.

Comment: I disagree that there are no elements semantically suitable for a wrapper. DIV is semantic-neutral, and only implies grouping of content - and that's exactly what a wrapper does: encloses the elements it wraps into a group.

Comment: I really wanted to come with a snappy comeback, but I wasn't able to, but maybe you can explain the abbreviation "div" to me? Don't seem that "semantic to me.

Answer (score 1):

If IE7 compatibility is not a requirement, use `display: table-cell;`:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;        
}
body > header, body > footer {
    background-color: red;
}
#wrapper > * {
    display: table-cell;
}
#wrapper > article {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#wrapper > aside {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/qFKA2/).

Comment: This sounds mighty interesting. Anyone care to elaborate on it? If in fact I don't care about IE7 and below, which I don't is this the smart approach?

Comment: @Zacariaz You're trying to emulate table-like features - elements in the same row sharing the same height - so it makes sense to use CSS table layout features.  The main obstacle to using them for everything is the lack of support in IE7 and before, which makes it impractical on many sites.

Comment: mkay. It is a bit easier that absolute positioning and since you can get IE8 for XP, I really don't care about older IE. I've also modified the approach a bit. Please do check it over and let me know if there's anything I should be concerned about: http://jsfiddle.net/qFKA2/5/ Basically I've removed the wrapper and the browser comparability. Also the position:relative, didn't seem necessary.

Comment: @Zacariaz I put the browser compatibility in because my default browser on this machine is Firefox 3.6 and that doesn't style the HTML5 elements by default, you'd also need that plus [html5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) for IE8 support.  The position relative was left over from your original code, I didn't change it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. There is a tiny bit of an issue though. I'll have to investigate this method further to really understand it, but as I use it now, it don't really work, as I'm supposed to use multiple article elements, and they should be displayed on top of each other. As I understand it, at this time, to make it work would take an article wrapper.

Comment: @Zacariaz Yep - if you want multiple elements then you have to wrap them into a 'cell'

Comment: Can't get it to work. Really have to go to bed. My head is spinning, but thanks for all the help.